# Make A File-Specific Bash Alias

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell

I'm on a mac and I've recently found out about bash aliases. Take this following one as an example:

```
# Python shortcut
alias c.py="touch template.py && open template.py"
```

It creates a python file and then immediately opens it. I think It's a useful tool, but I'd like to improve it slightly. Every time this is run, it creates a file by the name 'template.py', which is fine as I can save it under a different name, however I'd like to be able to specify the name within the command itself. For example, something like:

```
alias c.py(filename)="touch filename.py && open filename.py"
```

How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `open` is just passing the file (once it exists) to your designated editor. What's your editor? Why not just use that? `vi some.py` is pretty easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function, not an alias.

```
editpy () {
  touch "$1.py" && open "$1.py"
}
```

Then you can run `editpy template` or `editpy newfile` or whatever you want. `$1` will expand to the first argument that the function is called with.

Answer (score -1):

Define it as a function and alias to that function.
Use `$1` in the function to access "first argument"

```
function c.py() {
  touch $1.py
  open $1.py
}

alias c.py=c.py
```

Comment: What's the point in having an `alias` of the same name as the function?

Comment: I was just showing it is possible. So the function can be named whatever you like.